# Sqoop import java code issue

Tags: java, sqoop

I am running the sqoop import using the java jar provided by mapr and the version is as below

sqoop-1.4.4-mapr-1408.jar

```
package com.cisco.executor;

import org.apache.sqoop.SqoopOptions;
import org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool;

public class SqoopImport {

    private static SqoopOptions SqoopOptions = new SqoopOptions();
    private static final String connection = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)PORT=1533))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME==Dedicated)))";
    private static final String username = "XXCTS_NITA_U";
    private static final String password = "******";
    private static final String tablename = "XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE";
    private static final String columns = "CONTRACT_ID,CONTRACT_NUMBER,CONTRACT_STS_CODE,CONTRACT_STATUS,SERVICE_LINE_ID,SERVICE_LINE_NAME,SERVICE_LINE_STS_CODE,SERVICE_LINE_STATUS,SERVICE_LINE_NUMBER,HDR_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID,HDR_CUST_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,HDR_PARTY_ID,HDR_CUSTOMER_NAME,LINE_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID,LINE_CUST_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,LINE_PARTY_ID,LINE_CUSTOMER_NAME,BILL_TO_SITE_USE_ID,BILL_TO_SITE_USE_NAME,BILL_TO_SITE_USE_STS,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_ID,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_NUMBER,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_STS,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_SITE_ID,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_SITE_STS,BILL_TO_PARTY_ID,BILL_TO_PARTY_NUMBER,BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_NAME,BILL_TO_PARTY_STS,BILL_TO_PARTY_SITE_ID,BILL_TO_PARTY_SITE_STS,BILL_TO_LOCATION_ID,BILL_TO_COUNTRY,BILL_TO_STATE_PROV,BILL_TO_CITY,BILL_TO_POSTAL_CODE,COVERAGE_TEMPLATE_ID,COVERAGE_TEMPLATE_NAME,COVERAGE_TEMPLATE_DESC,COVERAGE_BEGIN_DATE,COVERAGE_END_DATE,SERVICE_SALES_REP_USR_ID,SERVICE_SALES_REP_USR_NAME,SERVICE_LINE_INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,BILLTO_CSC_ID,BILLTO_CSC_NAME,BILLTO_GU_ID,BILLTO_GU_NAME,BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_SALES_CHANNEL,CURRENCY_CODE,CONTRACT_LIST_AMT,CONTRACT_NET_AMT,USD_CONTRACT_LIST_AMT,USD_CONTRACT_NET_AMT,ACCOUNT_TEAM,RENEWAL_SSR,RENEWAL_TEAM,SALES_REGION,ADVANCE_CONTRACT_FLAG,EARLIEST_END_DATE,SERVICE_LINE_TERMINATED_DATE,SVC_LINE_TERMINATION_REASON,CONTRACT_TERMINATED_DATE,USD_CONV_RATE,PRICE_TYPE,NET_VALUE,COTERM_DATE,MARKETING_PROGRAM,MASTER_AGREEMENT_END_DATE,DISCOUNT_PERCENT,PRORATE_FLAG,RGP_ID,CREATION_DATE,CREATED_BY,LAST_UPDATE_DATE,LAST_UPDATED_BY,LAST_UPDATED_LOGIN,REQUEST_ID,PROGRAM_UPDATE_DATE,PROGRAM_APPLICATION_ID,PROGRAM_ID,ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY,ATTRIBUTE1,ATTRIBUTE2,ATTRIBUTE3,ATTRIBUTE4,ATTRIBUTE5,ATTRIBUTE6,ATTRIBUTE7,ATTRIBUTE8,ATTRIBUTE9,ATTRIBUTE10,ATTRIBUTE11,ATTRIBUTE12,ATTRIBUTE13,ATTRIBUTE14,ATTRIBUTE15,ATTRIBUTE16,ATTRIBUTE17,ATTRIBUTE18,ATTRIBUTE19,ATTRIBUTE20,ACCOUNT_SSR,SHELL_CONTRACT_FLAG,CONTRACT_START_DATE,CONTRACT_END_DATE";
    private static final String[] cols = columns.split(",");
    private static final String splitby = "CONTRACT_NUMBER";
    private static final String boundaryquery = "select (select min(CONTRACT_NUMBER) from XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE) as minid ,(select max(CONTRACT_NUMBER) from XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE) as maxid from dual";
    private static final String targetdir = "//app//dev//SmartAnalytics//sqoop_temp//XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE";  
    private static final int mappers = 4;
    private static final String nullString = "\\N";
    private static final String hivetable = "installbase.XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE";
    private static final boolean flagTrue = true;
    private static final String mapcolumnshive = "CONTRACT_ID=BIGINT,SERVICE_LINE_ID=BIGINT,HDR_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID=BIGINT,HDR_PARTY_ID=BIGINT,LINE_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID=BIGINT,LINE_PARTY_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_SITE_USE_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_SITE_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_PARTY_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_PARTY_SITE_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_LOCATION_ID=BIGINT,COVERAGE_TEMPLATE_ID=BIGINT,COVERAGE_BEGIN_DATE=TIMESTAMP,COVERAGE_END_DATE=TIMESTAMP,SERVICE_LINE_INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=BIGINT,BILLTO_CSC_ID=BIGINT,BILLTO_GU_ID=BIGINT,CONTRACT_LIST_AMT=BIGINT,CONTRACT_NET_AMT=BIGINT,USD_CONTRACT_LIST_AMT=BIGINT,USD_CONTRACT_NET_AMT=BIGINT,EARLIEST_END_DATE=TIMESTAMP,SERVICE_LINE_TERMINATED_DATE=TIMESTAMP,CONTRACT_TERMINATED_DATE=TIMESTAMP,USD_CONV_RATE=BIGINT,NET_VALUE=BIGINT,MASTER_AGREEMENT_END_DATE=TIMESTAMP,DISCOUNT_PERCENT=BIGINT,PRORATE_FLAG=STRING,RGP_ID=BIGINT,CREATION_DATE=TIMESTAMP,CREATED_BY=BIGINT,LAST_UPDATE_DATE=TIMESTAMP,LAST_UPDATED_BY=BIGINT,LAST_UPDATED_LOGIN=BIGINT,REQUEST_ID=BIGINT,PROGRAM_UPDATE_DATE=TIMESTAMP,PROGRAM_APPLICATION_ID=BIGINT,PROGRAM_ID=BIGINT,ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY=STRING,ATTRIBUTE1=STRING,ATTRIBUTE2=STRING,ATTRIBUTE3=STRING,ATTRIBUTE4=STRING,ATTRIBUTE5=STRING,ATTRIBUTE6=STRING,ATTRIBUTE7=STRING,ATTRIBUTE8=STRING,ATTRIBUTE9=STRING,ATTRIBUTE10=STRING,ATTRIBUTE11=STRING,ATTRIBUTE12=STRING,ATTRIBUTE13=STRING,ATTRIBUTE14=STRING,ATTRIBUTE15=STRING,ATTRIBUTE16=STRING,ATTRIBUTE17=STRING,ATTRIBUTE18=STRING,ATTRIBUTE19=STRING,ATTRIBUTE20=STRING,ACCOUNT_SSR=STRING,SHELL_CONTRACT_FLAG=STRING,CONTRACT_START_DATE=TIMESTAMP,CONTRACT_END_DATE=TIMESTAMP";


    private static void setUp()
    {
        SqoopOptions.setConnectString(connection);
        SqoopOptions.setUsername(username);
        SqoopOptions.setPassword(password);
        SqoopOptions.setTableName(tablename);
        SqoopOptions.setColumns(cols);
        SqoopOptions.setSplitByCol(splitby);
        SqoopOptions.setBoundaryQuery(boundaryquery);
        SqoopOptions.setTargetDir(targetdir);
        SqoopOptions.setNumMappers(mappers);
        SqoopOptions.setNullStringValue(nullString);
        SqoopOptions.setNullNonStringValue(nullString);
        SqoopOptions.setHiveTableName(hivetable);
        SqoopOptions.setHiveImport(flagTrue);
        SqoopOptions.setOverwriteHiveTable(flagTrue);
        SqoopOptions.setMapColumnHive(mapcolumnshive);      
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static int runIt() {
        int res;
        res = new ImportTool().run((com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions) SqoopOptions);
        if (res != 0) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Sqoop API Failed - return code : "+Integer.toString(res));
        }
        return res;
      }

}
```

Main Program:

```
package com.cisco.executor;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MainProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Class c = Class.forName("com.cisco.executor.SqoopImport");
            Object o = c.newInstance();
            Method setUp = c.getDeclaredMethod("setUp", null);
            Method runIt = c.getDeclaredMethod("runIt", null);
            setUp.setAccessible(true);
            runIt.setAccessible(true);
            setUp.invoke(o, null);
            runIt.invoke(o, null);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The program throws error as below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.sqoop.SqoopOptions.<clinit>(SqoopOptions.java:54)
    at com.cisco.executor.SqoopImport.<clinit>(SqoopImport.java:8)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at com.cisco.executor.MainProgram.main(MainProgram.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 5 more
```

I tried searching in google but did not get any appropriate information to resolve the issue. Can someone suggest me what is going wrong in my code.

Comment: Also include `log4j.jar` in your classpath

Comment: It is already included in my classpath

Comment: Make sure build path contains those 2 jars. If you are using eclipse `Right click on project -> properties -> java build path`  to check those two jar files exist. If not add them to the build path by `right clickign on jar ->Build path-> add to Build path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception means that you don't have the [apache commons-logging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/) jar in your classpath.

You need to add this jar to your project.